# Issue solving the following equation:

Tags: geometry, exponential-function

I am new to this so I am not too sure how this works. But I am trying to do some university work and I have to do a math module with it. This these questions came up:

*4. [6] The table below gives 210Pb activities in a marine sediment core.

| Depth, L (cm) | 210Pb activity, AL (Bq kg^-1) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 247 |
| 1.5 | 199 |
| 2 | 160 |
| 2.5 | 123 |
| 3 | 101 |
| 3.5 | 78 |
| 4 | 62 |
| 4.5 | 46 |
| 5 | 38 |

Assume the following equation applies
$$ A_l = A_0\exp((-λL)/S). $$

With question a.

I was thinking perhaps that I may need to get the equation somehow into the form of $y = mx + C$. $C$ is obviously is $0$ in this case and I am assuming that $A_0$ is $y$, and I am thinking that $L=x$ and then the remaining parts of the equation are $m$ but I am not too sure how to get L as the x part of $y = mx + c.$

Where $A_l$ is the activity at depth $L (Bq kg^{-1}),$  $A_0$ is the activity at zero depth ($L = 0$ cm), $λ$ is the decay constant ($0.031 yr^{-1}$ for 210Pb), $L$ is the sediment depth (cm) and $S$ is the sediment accumulation rate (cm $yr^{-1}$).

a) Transform the above equation into straight line form.

(b) By plotting the data estimate the value of $A_0$ and $S.$

Comment: Please include the question within the post, by *typing it in*. Never rely on links to speak for you. I'd rather help formant a sincere attempt to take the time to write out your question, than chase links.  We are all, even moderators, volunteers on this site.  Using links only, diminishes the number of users willing to volunteer our help.  Let me know if or when you try your best to type in your problem statement, and I'll gladly help to format it.  Let me know using @amWhy ...

Comment: First step: You are asked implicitly to take the logarithm of the relationship, $\ln(A_L)=\underbrace{\ln(A_0)}_c+\underbrace{(-(\lambda/S))}_mL$

Comment: ... therefore you must work on the (natural) logarithm of your second line...

Comment: @JeanMarie Whats x?

Comment: @amWhy Ok, I have done that.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: $x$ is $L$.....

Comment: @amWhy How do you do it then?